# Xml Serialization for Unusual Connection Protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

In my application I have a `PacketList` class and `Packet` class. I'd like to be able to use the serialization helpers on `PacketList` to come up with something like the desired output, but have no idea what direction to go in.

I am writing a program to imitate a server which has a peculiar protocol for sending data.

Client sends data with format: `COMMAND|ARGUMENT_0|ARGUMENT_1|ARGUMENT_2|...|ARGUMENT_N\0`. Where `COMMAND` could be something like `MOVE` or `LOGIN`.

The server would respond in the format:

```
<p c='COUNT'>
    <m p='N' p0='COMMAND_0' p1='ARUGMENT_0' ... pN='ARGUMENT_N'/>
    <m p='N' p0='COMMAND_1' p1='ARUGMENT_0' ... pN='ARGUMENT_N'/>
    <m p='N' p0='COMMAND_2' p1='ARUGMENT_0' ... pN='ARGUMENT_N'/>
    <m p='N' p0='COMMAND_3' p1='ARUGMENT_0' ... pN='ARGUMENT_N'/>
    ...
    <m p='N' p0='COMMAND_COUNT' p1='ARUGMENT_0' ... pN='ARGUMENT_N'/>
</p>
```

Where `COMMAND_0` could be something like `UPDATE_POSITION` or `AUTHENTICATED`.

Yes, this is a silly way of doing things. No, I don't know why it's done this way. No, I can't change it.

Anyways, I am looking to emulate the way that the server sends the packet back to the client. What I have gotten so far is:

```
XmlWriterSettings _Settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true
};
StringBuilder _Xml = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter _Writer = XmlWriter.Create(_Xml, _Settings);
_Writer.WriteStartElement("p");
    _Writer.WriteAttributeString("c", "1");
    _Writer.WriteStartElement("m");
        _Writer.WriteAttributeString("p", "2");
        _Writer.WriteAttributeString("p0", "COMMAND");
        _Writer.WriteAttributeString("p1", "ARGUMENT_0");
        _Writer.WriteAttributeString("p2", "ARGUMENT_1");
    _Writer.WriteEndElement(); // </m>
_Writer.WriteEndElement(); // </p>
_Writer.Flush();
Console.WriteLine(_Xml.ToString());
```

This works properly and outputs:

```
<p c="1">
  <m p="2" p0="COMMAND" p1="ARGUMENT_0" p2="ARGUMENT_1" />
</p>
```

However, I'd like to implement this in a cleaner way.

My `PacketList` basically contains a list of `Packet`s, and `Packet` contains a `String _Command` and `String[] _Arguments`.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are currently doing it is the best.  I would say to use the XmlSerializer and decorate your Packet and PacketList class's properties with the appropriate Xml*Attribute attributes to control the way the output is formatted, but since you need to write attributes corresponding to a collection (p0, p1, p2, etc.) this will not work.

Since you need to write such a weird format, it makes sense to write it manually the way you currently are.

Andrew

Comment: I thought that I was in the right direction, but it was so complicated I didn't think it could be right. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I second Andrew's answer.

AFAIK, there's no way to do it unless you write your own serializer, since you compose two levels of data elements (with dynamic number of elements!) as **attributes** in a single XML element. There's no sense doing it, and, well, XmlSerializer needs **some** sense in order to work using just Reflection.